# Webpack - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined jquery

Tags: jquery, webpack

I'm using webpack bundler for compiling react js code. However, I'm facing issue while working with third party libraries like jquery and velocity js.

I've imported jquery in custom js file at the top however, i'm still getting error.

```
/* Import libraries stylesheet */
import '../shared/lib/normalize.css';
import '../shared/lib/grid.css';
import '../shared/lib/tiny-scrollbar/tinyscrollbar.css';

/* Import main stylesheet */
import './main.scss';

/* Import libraries script */
import '../shared/lib/jquery-1.12.3.min.js';
import '../shared/lib/tiny-scrollbar/jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js';
import '../shared/lib/velocity.min.js';
import '../components/card/cards.js';

/* Import main component */
import './main.jsx';
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Added jquery plugin in webpack solved the issue.

```
 plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery"
        })
    ]
```

Comment: Why do you need all three lines ($, jQuery, window.jQuery)?